# in postgresql 13, how do i ensure a SupportRequestSelectivity is made?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to include a sensitivity operator in a function. My issue is that when
I have my function, I get a call to SupportRequestSimplify, but not SupportRequestSensitivity. It isn't obvious what I am doing incorrect.

My c function is:

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(pgq3c_join_selectivity);
Datum pgq3c_join_selectivity(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
  Node     *rawreq = (Node *) PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
  Node     *ret = NULL;

  elog(WARNING,"in pgq3c_join_selectivity %d %d %d",
       rawreq->type,T_SupportRequestSelectivity,T_SupportRequestSimplify);

  
  if (IsA(rawreq, SupportRequestSelectivity))
    {
      elog(WARNING,"found SupportRequestSelectivity");
    }
  if (IsA(rawreq, SupportRequestSimplify))
    {
      elog(WARNING,"found SupportRequestSimplify");
    }

  PG_RETURN_POINTER(ret);
}
```

my sql function code is:

```
-- a selectivity function for the q3c join function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION q3c_join_selectivity(internal)
       RETURNS internal
       AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 'pgq3c_join_selectivity'
       LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT ;
```

and my function definition is:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION q3c_join(leftra double precision, leftdec double precision,
                    rightra double precision, rightdec double precision,
                    radius double precision)
        RETURNS boolean AS
'
SELECT (((q3c_ang2ipix($3,$4)>=(q3c_nearby_it($1,$2,$5,0))) AND (q3c_ang2ipix($3,$4)<=(q3c_nearby_it($1,$2,$5,1))))
    OR ((q3c_ang2ipix($3,$4)>=(q3c_nearby_it($1,$2,$5,2))) AND (q3c_ang2ipix($3,$4)<=(q3c_nearby_it($1,$2,$5,3))))
    OR ((q3c_ang2ipix($3,$4)>=(q3c_nearby_it($1,$2,$5,4))) AND (q3c_ang2ipix($3,$4)<=(q3c_nearby_it($1,$2,$5,5))))
    OR ((q3c_ang2ipix($3,$4)>=(q3c_nearby_it($1,$2,$5,6))) AND (q3c_ang2ipix($3,$4)<=(q3c_nearby_it($1,$2,$5,7))))) 
    AND q3c_sindist($1,$2,$3,$4)<POW(SIN(RADIANS($5)/2),2)
    AND ($5::double precision ==<<>>== ($1,$2,$3,$4)::q3c_type)
' LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE COST 10 SUPPORT q3c_join_selectivity;
```

When I run my function, I get:

```
(base) [greg.hennessy@localhost ~]$ psql q3c_test
Timing is on.
Output format is unaligned.
psql (13.4)
Type "help" for help.

q3c_test=# select count(*) from test as a, test1 as b where  q3c_join(a.ra,a.dec,b.ra,b.dec,.01);
WARNING:  in pgq3c_join_selectivity 417 418 417
WARNING:  found SupportRequestSimplify
count
153
(1 row)
Time: 9701.717 ms (00:09.702)
q3c_test=#
```

So, I see a call where I am asked for a SupportRequestSimplify, but
not a SupportRequestSelectivity.

I admit to not being an expert in postgres internals hacking. Is there something
obvious I am doing incorrect? How do I ensure my support Function is asked
for a SupportRequestSelectivity?